# Use differentiable function to approximate continuous function

Tags: analysis, approximation

Let $f$ be a continuous monotone increasing function on $[a,b]$. I want to show for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist a monotone increasing function $g\in C^1[a,b]$ such that
$$
\max_{x\in[a,b]}|g-f|<\epsilon
$$
Could anyone give me some hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: One possibility is to extend $f$ to an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ and to approximate by Friedrichs' mollifier. Monotonicity is preserved then.

Comment: @Gerd Is there any naive and constructive method, very thanks.

Comment: There is a simple Probabilistic solution, if you are interested.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Very thanks if you can provide one, I'm quite interested

Comment: There are [spline methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) to approximate monotone functions. That are even implemented in R, MatLab, etc.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at $g(x)=\frac {f(x)-f(a)} {f(b)-f(a)}$ for $a<x<b$, $1$ for $x \geq b$ and $0$ for $x \leq a$ we  can reduce this problem to the case when $f$ is a CDF on $\mathbb R$.  Can we approximate a continuous CDF by as continuously differentiable CDF? Probabilistically this is very simple. Let $X$ be a r.v. with CDF $F$. Let $Y $ have some nice CDF with a continuous density, say standard normal CDF. Let $F_n$ be the distribution function of $X+\frac Y n$. Then $F_n$ has  a continuous density $F_n'$ and $F_n \to F$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

[One way to show that $F_n$ is continuously differentiable is to use the inversion foumula for charactersitic functions. Note that the  charactersitic functions of $X+\frac Y n$ is integrable. You can also prove this by just Calculus by writing $F_n$ as  convolution of two CDF's]

Answer (score 2):

W.l.o.g. let $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and let $f \in C([0,1])$. The Bernstein Polynomials
$$
B_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f(k/n)x^k(1-x)^{n-k}
$$
have the derivative
$$
B_n'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}f(k/n)(kx^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k}-(n-k)x^k(1-x)^{n-k-1})
$$
$$
=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k} [f((k+1)/n)-f(k/n)] x^k(1-x)^{n-1-k}.
$$
If $f$ is increasing then clearly $B_n'(x) \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$ and $(B_n)$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.